# TikZ - Random superposition of drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf, sudoku

I would like to imitate the first page of [this pdf](http://www.lifl.fr/~delahaye/dnalor/SudokuSciam2006.pdf) by using the following code for the hard job of making the sudoku grids.

Indeed the problem is just to superpose several sudoku grids, and not to draw this sudoku grids individually.

### CODE

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes}

    \tikzset {
        digit/.style = {
            minimum height = 5mm,
            minimum width = 5mm,
            anchor = center
        }
    }

    \newcounter{row}
    \newcounter{col}

    \newcommand\setrow[9]{
        \setcounter{col}{1}
        \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
            \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
            \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
            \node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}}] at (\x, \y) {\n};
            \stepcounter{col}
        }
        \stepcounter{row}
    }

    \newcommand\shownumber{
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} {
            \node[font=\tiny,color=gray] at (\x-0.5,9.5) {\x};
            \node[font=\tiny,color=gray] at (-.5,9.5-\x) {\x};
        }
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \begin{scope}
        \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
        \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

        \setcounter{row}{1}
        \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
        \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
        \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

        \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
        \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
        \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

        \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
        \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
        \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

        \shownumber{}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like the code below? I only reuse your nice  `tikzpicture`, make a white background, use the `rotate` option and superpose with `hspace` and  `vspace` the pictures.

The output is as here:
[image: Output of code]

If this helps you, I am sure you can adapt this trick to make the whole picture as you want.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes}

\tikzset {
    digit/.style = {
        minimum height = 5mm,
        minimum width = 5mm,
        anchor = center
    }
}

\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}

\newcommand\setrow[9]{
    \setcounter{col}{1}
    \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
        \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
        \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
        \node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}}] at (\x, \y) {\n};
        \stepcounter{col}
    }
    \stepcounter{row}
}

\newcommand\shownumber{
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} {
        \node[font=\tiny,color=gray] at (\x-0.5,9.5) {\x};
        \node[font=\tiny,color=gray] at (-.5,9.5-\x) {\x};
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\begin{scope}
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \shownumber{}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=25,scale=.5]
\begin{scope}
\filldraw[white] (0, 0) rectangle (9, 9);
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \shownumber{}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-9cm}
\hspace{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=15,scale=.5]
\begin{scope}
\filldraw[white] (0, 0) rectangle (9, 9);
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \shownumber{}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is only one small problem with the numbers of rows and columns but I do not really want to use them.

Comment: Delete `\shownumber` commands. You might also want to rotate the numbers in the grid: add `transform shape` to the nodes: `\node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}},transform shape] at (\x, \y) {\n};`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `sudoku` package (to draw sudoku grid) and `pgf-blur` tikz library (to add a blurred shadow):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{sudoku}
\setlength\sudokusize{5cm}
\renewcommand*\sudokuformat[1]{\small #1}
\setlength\sudokuthickline{1pt}
\setlength\sudokuthinline{.4pt}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadows.blur,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  sudoku grid/.style={
    fill=white,text width=\sudokusize,
    draw,inner sep=2mm,blur shadow,
  },
  every shadow/.style={
    shadow opacity=20,
    shadow blur steps=20,
    shadow blur radius=.5em,
    shadow xshift=.5em,
    shadow yshift=-.5em,
    shadow scale=1,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rotate=30,sudoku grid] at (-2,1){%
    \begin{sudoku-block}
      |2|5| | |3| |9| |1|.
      | |1| | | |4| | | |.
      |4| |7| | | |2| |8|.
      | | |5|2| | | | | |.
      | | | | |9|8|1| | |.
      | |4| | | |3| | | |.
      | | | |3|6| | |7|2|.
      | |7| | | | | | |3|.
      |9| |3| | | |6| |4|.
    \end{sudoku-block}%
  };

  \node[rotate=-45,sudoku grid] at (3,1){%
    \begin{sudoku-block}
      | |2| | |3| |9| |7|.
      | |1| | | | | | | |.
      |4| |7| | | |2| |8|.
      | | |5|2| | | |9| |.
      | | | |1|8| |7| | |.
      | |4| | | |3| | | |.
      | | | | |6| | |7|1|.
      | |7| | | | | | | |.
      |9| |3| |2| |6| |5|.
    \end{sudoku-block}
  };

  \node[sudoku grid] at (0,1){%
    \begin{sudoku-block}
      |2|5| | |3| |9| |1|.
      | |1| | | |4| | | |.
      |4| |7| | | |2| |8|.
      | | |5|2| | | | | |.
      | | | | |9|8|1| | |.
      | |4| | | |3| | | |.
      | | | |3|6| | |7|2|.
      | |7| | | | | | |3|.
      |9| |3| | | |6| |4|.
    \end{sudoku-block}%
  };

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=3mm,fill=white]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```